# Using a vector in within() with a replacement function in R (also memisc is involved.)

Tags: r, package

So my title is wordy mostly because I don't actually know what I'm talking about.  I've been struggling for two days now with trying to use the package [memisc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/memisc.pdf) so that I can discriminate between different types of NAs in my data. (*Sidenote: This is already a compromise I'm unhappy about making, but there weren't really any other good options. If you think you have one, I could make another separate question for that.*)

Skipping through all of what brought me to this point, here's where we are right now.

```
#install.packages("memisc")
library(memisc)
df <- data.frame('a' = 1:4, 'b' = 2:5, 'c' = 3:6)
ds <- data.set(df)
descs <- c("This is a", "This is b", "This is c")
```

Obviously my data is much larger or I wouldn't be bothering with this at all, but maybe that needs to be said just in case.

Here's what happens when I try to give an 'item' a description:

### Things that work

```
ds <- within(ds, description(df.a) <- "test") # The way the package suggests
description(ds$df.a) == "test"  # TRUE, as expected

description(ds$df.a) <- "test2" # Calling it with a name
description(ds$df.a) == "test2" # TRUE too
```

The end goal is to have all 176 columns in my "data.set" described by the already-existing, long-winded descriptions I have in a vector. So I need to have it accept a vector or use apply or iterate over it somehow, and I'm comfortable with my options there. But everything I've tried thus far to get the replacement function `description()` to work in a way that will accept references to objects somewhere along the line has failed.

### Things that don't work

```
description(ds[, 1]) <- "test"  # Calling it by number doesn't wirj
description(ds$df.a) == "test"  # FALSE

test_name <- "df.a"  
ds <- within(ds, description(get(test_name)) <- "test") # No.

test_name <- quote("df.a")
ds <- within(ds, description(eval(test_name)) <- "test") # No.
```

Whether I use `get()`, `quote()/eval()` or some similar setup, I get the same style of error:

```
> ds <- within(ds, description(get(test_name)) <- "test")
Error in description(get(test_name)) <- "test" : 
  could not find function "get<-"
```

So I thought I would be creative and call the function itself with both values...

```
ds <- within(ds, 'description<-'(test_name, "test3"))
description(ds$df.a) == "test3"  # FALSE
```

And that also fails, presumably because `description()` is a wrapper (I think?) for another function (method?), `annotate()`, which has the same thing going on.

### Not mine, obv, but just for reference

```
#### Description function ####
"description<-" <- function(x,value){
  annotation(x)["description"] <- value
  x
}

#### I'd paste the stupid method code, but stackoverflow  doesn't ####
#### think it's properly formatted as code when I do, so pfft.    ####
```

## Actual question

How the heck do I take my data.set, *ds*, and assign the vector of descriptions, *descs*, to the apprpopriate items?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you need to use `within` (perhaps there is a good explanation in the package docs), but I don't see why in this instance you can't just use a `for` loop and do `for (i in seq_along(descs) ) description(ds[[i]]) <- descs[i]`. Check with `description(ds)`? As `description<-` is a replacement function.

Comment: This works perfectly, @SimonO'Hanlon. I had tried this first of all with `ds[, i]`, which didn't and still doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Comment: My guess would be the `memisc` `datasets` class doesn't support accessing a column via `[,` indexing and instead you have to use `list` indexing, ie. `[[]]`.

Comment: Well, thanks so much. I guess I'll just always try both forms in the future.  :)

Comment: Added an answer so that this can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`for (i in seq_along(descs) ) description(ds[[i]]) <- descs[i]`